# Cual es la mejor práctica para trabajar con TabView TabViewItem en NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

Soy nuevo usando NativeScript. Por un lado necesito saber si hay una forma un poco más eficiente que trabajar con `frames` o `views` dentro del `TabViewItem`.

Por el otro no entiendo bien el mensaje de error que tira el log de `ns` cuando el `TabViewItem` tiene más de un hijo: **"Changing the view of an already loaded TabViewItem is not currently supported"**. 
Gracias.